# Saving the form in Sharepoint to be saved in SP list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

How to create a custom form to submit.
 I have created a form in SharePoint Designer and once we click on the submit button in SharePoint I want it to be saved in a list. Can anyone tell me how I can do that.
Example:
Name:
Date:
Phone:
and then Submit button. which when selected show save in my list in SharePoint which can be used for viewing and printing.

Thanks
Mohammed

Comment: Just a query, Why you created a custom form? Why you didn't used default listforms of sharepoint list?

Answer (score 0):

**Hi,you should use Jquery or Java script to get this done easily,**

**Here you go,**
'
    var newTask;

```
$('#btnAddTask').click(function () {
    var taskTitle = $('#txtTaskTitle').val();
    var taskDesc = $('#txtTaskDescription').val();

    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var taskList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Tasks');
    // use ListItemCreationInformation to provide values..
    var taskItemInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    newTask = taskList.addItem(taskItemInfo);
    newTask.set_item('Title', taskTitle);
    // could set other fields here in same way..
    newTask.update();

    ctx.load(newTask);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(addTaskSuccess, addTaskFailure);

    function addTaskSuccess(sender, args) {
        $('#addResult').html("Task " + newTask.get_item('Title') + " added to the Tasks list");
    }

    function addTaskFailure(sender, args) {
        alert('Failed to add new task. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
});
```

'

**this for script just change the lists names and button names as your form SP designer,**

**more details in**

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/search?q=ajax